# Android Espresso Recording Assert for ImagesView in list View

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have just started using Espresso for Android app testing, I have a list adaptor which contains item, these item has imageview, I want to test how many items are in list those have imageview visible. i.e count of item have visible imageView.

Check image for better idea, This aim icon in green color need to be checked and count of all such items.

[image]

Comment: What you tried and what are the problems you faced? can you please describe the actual problem?

Comment: Please check out the following link to help you ask a well-rounded question. This will help us help you :)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Droid, I will keep this in mind, I am updating My question sorry!